# Where does it make sense to branch from when basically rewriting the codebase, if at all?

Tags: git

The repo is at a release, however development won't be continuing in that direction as almost everything will be refactored.

Branching from the tip would result in a large deletion commit, which wouldn't be all too bad but it doesn't feel right. Is there any convention for doing something like this? I would prefer to maintain the commit history without having to create a new repo.

Comment: Do you mean to say that they're not basing *any* of their work off of the existing release code and that they're writing it from scratch?  A refactor would imply that the code and its behavior remain functionally intact while changing around its internals.

Comment: There are definitely some modules that will be functionally equivalent, however some interfaces and components won't exist anymore. I suppose it's more a question of where do you draw the line of creating and not creating a new repo.

Comment: Sorry, refactor was probably not the right word in the original question.

Comment: No, I get the feeling that refactor was right.  Your team isn't likely going to drop *all* of their code and rewrite everything from scratch.  That's prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Actually I think you were spot on. It is, at its core, a refactoring, albeit a relatively extensive one. Probably just feeling the apprehension of having big, ugly commits in the interim. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice in this scenario:  continue branching in the same manner as before.

Git preserves the history of the code, and that is useful information to have to at least reference; observing the past way the code was written is still a valuable thing to have around.  This also guards against the very real scenario of not being able to roll back to an older state because the code was lost.

Removing files and removing code is just as natural of a thing to Git as adding files and code.  There's no reason to think that it's different, even if the code base as a whole will be radically* changed from what it was before.

<sup>*:  I should quantify - if you're planning on rewriting everything and matching up the APIs, then that is a new repository and the older one is sealed and *never looked at again*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely also continue branching for two reasons:

1. Commit history.  This is key.  A lot of the commits done at the
   start of any project tend to be large, unstructured and often
   unintelligible as the project is finding its feet.  It's not the
   code that's as important as the commit history.  Knowing *why* you
   deleted those 95 classes is often more useful than looking at what
   was in them
2. What if while you're working on your new refactoring you need to
   release a quick hotfix for the existing code?  If you'd branched from a previous commit you'd have to then maintain two massively diverged branches.